# vbs execute from network with credentials

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I need to run a setup.exe from the local network with credentials.

I was able to do this with a bat file, but the problem is, but i don't want the `cmd` window showing up when this is executing.

So from what i've read, a good option is to use a `vbs` script like this, except i can't find a way to use it with credentials.

```
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
shell.Run("\\192.168.0.100\Setup\setup.exe"), 0 , True
```

**Basically what i need is the equivalent of this batch script in vbs:**

```
net use Z: \\192.168.0.100\sh /user:user password /persistent:yes
start /d "Z:\Setup" setup.exe
```

Comment: Scratch that, instead use psexec. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may do this:

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "Z:", "\\192.168.0.100\sh", True, user, password

Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
shell.CurrentDirectory = "Z:\Setup"
shell.Run("setup.exe"), 0 , True
```

---

Note: MapNetworkDrive will fail if Z: is already mapped. You will need to handle that.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Yes the mapping is a problem, but i would need a way to unmap the drive after the setup is run.

Comment: And there is also a nasty vbs error if u click cancel instead of run for the setup.exe, but that is also another story.

Comment: To unmap, just use the RemoveNetworkDrive method, you should lookup for the WSH reference online for more details.

Comment: I tried this `WshNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "Z:"` after `shell.Run`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what is the error? have you tried `WshNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "Z:", True, True` ?

Comment: Yep that works aswell. This really helped me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

PSExec is what you want:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pstools.aspx

Like this:

```
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
shell.Run("psexec.exe -u User -p Password -accepteula \\192.168.0.100\Setup\setup.exe"), 0 , True
```

Documentation:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec

> Using PsExec
>
> Usage: psexec [\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p
>   psswd][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c
>   [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]
>
> -u    Specifies optional user name for login to remote computer.
>
> -p    Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this
>         you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.
>
> -accepteula   This flag suppresses the display of the license dialog.

Comment: Does this mean i have to have PsTools copied/installed on every machine where i need to run the setup.exe file?

Comment: You just need the psexec.exe executable. You can put it on a share somewhere or you could base64 encode the exe then put the base64 encoded info in your script. Either way would work fine.